# How to extract the computed value of a field which is an instance of the class ` FieldLenField ` of the "scapy" module from a packet?

Tags: python, scapy

I am trying to build a packet of a new protocol by the "scapy" module. In the packet layer for the new protocol, the first field is the field for an ID. Following is a length field which has the size of the payload of the new protocol as the value. And the next one is a field which has a MAC address as its value. The last one is the data payload. Below is the snapshot of my code:

```
from scapy.all import *

class MyLayer(Packet):
  name = "MyLayer"
  fields_desc = [BitField("id", 1, 16),
                 FieldLenField("len", None, length_of = "data"),
                 MACField("MACAddress", "00:00:00:00:00:00"),
                 StrLenField("data", "", length_from = lambda pkt: pkt.len)]


myLayer = MyLayer(data = "abcd1234")
myLayer.show2()
```

In the code above, the output of the function `show2` is as what I expect. But when I try to extract the computed value of the "len" field which is an instance of the class `FieldLenField` by the `len` property, I get `None` which is the default value I set for this field:

```
print(myLayer.len)
None
```

Could anyone kindly tell me what the correct way to extract the computed value of the "len" field should be? Thank you in advance.

Comment: What is the size of the FieldLenField?

Comment: @Tim Roberts  Because the default value of the parameter ` fmt ` of the class ` FieldLenField ` is ` H ` which stands for "unsigned short". I think the size should be 2 bytes.